# Java API resource ordering

Tags: java, resteasy

Tackling the problem of versioning an API that wasn't versioned previously, I'm running into an issue: I've got two resources set on the same URL endpoint:

```
@Path("/api/foo/")
public class FooResourceOne {

    @GET
    public Response getFoo () {
        return Response.ok("Hello from One").build();
    }
}

@Path("/api/foo/")
@Consumes("application/vnd.example.v2+json")
public class FooResourceTwo {

    @GET
    public Response getFoo () {
        return Response.ok("Hello from Two").build();
    }
}
```

The issue is, if you send a GET request with a `Content-Type` header (e.g. `Content-Type: application/json`) it goes to `FooResourceOne` for handling. And if you specify `Content-Type: application/vnd.example.v2+json`, it goes to `FooResourceTwo` properly. That's all well and good.

However, if you don't specify a Content-Type header at all, it goes to `FooResourceTwo`, which is not correct?

Not having a `@Consumes` annotation means "accepts any", but it seems "any" doesn't include "not specified"? Or rather "not specified" means handled by whomever (and load ordering is important)?

Is there a way to specify `FooResourceOne` is the Resource that should respond when no Content-Type header is given at all?

Comment: Which REST implementation are you using `Resteasy/CXF/Jersey ` ?

Comment: Are you consider to add a rest Filter and add to content-type the preferred header?

Comment: What happens when you add another method with just `@Path` and no `@Consumes` ?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera: a `Filter` may do it, but the `ServletRequest` class nor `HttpServletClass` seem to have a set/add header method, only getters. How do you modify the request and continue to pass it up the chain?

Answer (score 0):

I managed a workaround that doesn't fix the underlying issue, but at least alleviates the symptom. The Resteasy `Filter` and `PreProcessInterceptor` classes are able to detect when a request comes in with no `Content-Type` header, but can't then do anything about it other than throw an error. So, my workaround is for `FooResourceTwo` to first check and see if there is no header set:

```
@Path("/api/foo/")
public class FooResourceOne {

    @GET
    public Response getFoo () {
        return Response.ok("Hello from One").build();
    }
}

@Path("/api/foo/")
@Consumes("application/vnd.example.v2+json")
public class FooResourceTwo {
    @Inject
    private FooResourceOne oldResource;

    @GET
    public Response getFoo (@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (request.getHeader("content-type") == null) {
            // No, no, Resteasy; go this way...
            return oldResource.getFoo();
        }
        return Response.ok("Hello from Two").build();
    }
}
```